# How to use SharpNLP in my xamarin android app

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am new to xamarin I would like to use SharpNlp in my xamarin andriod app I have no use how to do that please suggest me some links or some steps to do that thanks in advance

Comment: Check https://github.com/AlexPoint/OpenNlp . You can install it in nuget manager .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Hi I tried that but it is not installing through nuget manager in xamarin android

Comment: Why is it not installing? What's the error message you get?

Comment: @Saamer this is the error I am getting
ErrorNU1202 Package OpenNLP 1.3.5 is not compatible with monoandroid90 (MonoAndroid,Version=v9.0). Package OpenNLP 1.3.5 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)

Comment: Do you have a Core project in your solution?

Comment: Core project means I didnt get what you are asking could you please explain me I am new to xamarin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution Explorer can looks like this:

[image: Solution Explorer]

If you can't see it when you open your solution, you can display it in the window by going to View->Pads->Solution (VS for Mac).

If you look at your Solution Explorer, you can see that there is an Android project (xxx.Android) whose build has a Target Framework monoandroid90 (MonoAndroid,Version=v9.0). You are trying to add the OpenNLP nuget to that project, and hence you see that error.

You have to make sure that you have a Core project (xxx or xxx.Core) whose build Target framework resembles .NET Standard as shown below, or net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5) that was mentioned in your error message. And then add the nuget package to that project. Then using a ViewModel or Services layer, you can use the NLP from that Core project into your Android app.

You can add a Core project if there isn't already one, by right clicking on the Solution (Top level element in the solution explorer), and Selecting "Add->Add New Project->.NetStandard/Class/Portable Library" [image: Core project build Target framework]

Then, when you double click on the Core project in the Solution Explorer, you'll be able to change whatever Target Framework you want.

---

And here's more documentation on [how to use OpenNLP](https://github.com/AlexPoint/OpenNlp)

Comment: Hello I Installed openNlp but I have no idea how where to add the training files likes EnglishTok.nbin,EnglishSD.nbin etc in my project please tell me how to add those files to my project and how to give that Path in my code Thanks in advance

Comment: You can just put it in your resources folder, but it has to be the right format. Why don’t you use a Sample that’s provided first?

Comment: Hello @Saamer thanks I added that but I am getting this error could you please help me to remove this thanks in advance   
Error :Can not resolve reference: `SharpWordNet`, referenced by `Ocr PRo.Core` > `OpenNLP`. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for `SharpWordNet`, or remove the reference to `Ocr PRo.Core`.

Comment: Hey Kiran, create a separate Question for that so that others who face that problem are able to search it!